# MECE statistics

Tags: probability, descriptive-statistics, mathematical-statistics, linear-algebra

Consider a sample of a real quantity $X$. Say that we divide this sample into two mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive (MECE) groups.

Say we know the mean and median of these two groups, $\mu_1$, $\tilde{\mu}_1$, $\mu_2$, $\tilde{\mu}_2$, respectively. What can we say about the mean and median of the original sample, $\mu$ and $\tilde{\mu}$?

For example, can the following conditions occur?

- $\mu$< $\mu_1$ **and** $\mu$< $\mu_2$ ? (mean of the full sample smaller than the two  individual group means)
- $\tilde{\mu}$< $\tilde{\mu_1}$ **and** $\tilde{\mu}$< $\tilde{\mu_2}$ ? (median of the full sample smaller than the two individual group medians)

Comment: This seems rather like routine bookwork. How does the question arise?

Comment: You should also explicitly define your sample median when the sample size is even.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b The question came up when conditioning the analysis of an A/B experiment on a factor that splits the full sample in two groups. I have worked out the algebraic inequalities for both conditions and I believe the answer to these two questions is false, and in general it made me wonder about questions regarding these "MICE statistics".

Comment: @Glen_b, by the median of a sample $X$ of size even, I am referring to the average of the two middle values of the sorted sample, that is: $\frac{1}{2} \left(X_\text{sorted}[\frac{N}{2}] + X_\text{sorted}[\frac{N}{2}+1]\right)$.

Comment: Note also that if you're talking about sample quantities, your notation should not relate to population quantities (that is, use $\bar{x}$ to refer to a sample mean, not $\mu$, which is conventionally a population mean.

Comment: @rightskewed in your example $\mu = \frac{1+2-3-4}{4} = \frac{-4}{4} = -1$